# PHP Socket timeout connection check

Tags: php, sockets

I am a newbie at PHP so I am wondering if anyone could help me.

I made a script using lots of work, even tough it's really easy but I just suck.

But yeah, if my website is on, this scripts shows it.

But if it doesn't load it takes a million hours for it to say that.

How can I set the maximum time for the script?

Thank you verry much

(I've searched a lot around Stack Overflow for a solution to this and all answers I found were unclear or not working for me.)

```
    <?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$ports = array(3000, 80);

foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        if($port == 80)
        {
        echo "web: ONLINE";
        }

       if($port == 3000)
        {
        echo 'client: ONLINE';
        }

        fclose($connection);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: See the docs at http://php.net/fsockopen pay close attention to $timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can define the maximum timeout in the [5th argument of the `fsockopen` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php):

```
$connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10); // timeout at 10 seconds
```

Side note, by passing `$errno` and `$errstr` you can now retrieve and subsequently output a little bit more detail in your error:

```
echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\r\n";
echo '<p>Error Number ' . $errno . ': ' . $errstr . '</p>'."\r\n";
```

Comment: Thx dude :D, what is the $errno? should i add that variable too or?

Comment: The `$errno` and `$errstr` are actually passed to the function as references to be filled in by `fsockopen` if there's any error or trouble. You can echo those out later to provide more descriptive messages as to _why_ the connection failed!

Comment: @NubGuy No problem! Please make sure you mark off the answer that helped you the most as accepted. It can be done by clicking the "checkmark" right below the down/up vote arrows for the answer. Also welcome to SO.

Comment: Im new to this forum need 15rep for that if i got that i would

Comment: @NubGuy You're confusing accepting an answer with upvoting. There's just a 15-minute time limit for accepting an answer, you should be able to now. [See this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information!

Answer (score 1):

Have a quick look at the [documentation](http://php.net/fsockopen) and you'll see: parameter 5, `float $timeout`, is able to do that.

You should also check for `$connection` being `false`. That occurs if your timeout has been reached, or if any other error occured.